# How can I get the elements of a 2-D List in Java? For example, List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, nested-lists

How can I find the elements of a 2-D List in Java?

I have a function that has a parameter of `List<List<Integer>>` and I want to know how to find the rows and columns of this List.

Answer (score 2):

If you take like

```
List<List<Integer>> obj
```

Then you can access like

```
obj.get(current_row).get(current_column);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have asked for help getting the "rows" and "columns" from a `List<List<Integer>>` parameter.

The get the "rows", it's pretty straightforward:

```
List<List<Integer>> table;
for (List<Integer> row : table) {
    // do something with 'row'
}
```

Columns are not straightforward though:

```
List<List<Integer>> table; // assumed to not be empty
int columnCount = table.get(0).size();
for (int columnNumber = 0; i < columnCount; columnNumber++) {
    List<Integer> column = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Integer> row : table) {
        column.add(row.get(columnNumber));
    }
    // do something with 'column'
}
```

To save on reprocessing for each access to column data, you could store the columns in a `List<List<Integer>>` variable, then access those similarly to accessing rows.

Answer (score 0):

The List api defines an api [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists;
// get, then get again
Integer integer = listOfLists.get(row).get(column);
```

The first "get" in the chain returns a `List<Interger>`, so you get again to get the integer

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would do if you had an `int[][]` except that you would need to use the retrieval methods of the lists.

The easiest way is to use the fact that Lists implement the `Iterable` interface.

So you could

```java
      //  create some data

      List<List<Integer>> listofLists = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         listofLists.add(Arrays.asList(1 * i, 2 * i, 3 * i));
      }
```

Display it

```java
      for (List<Integer> list : listofLists) {
         System.out.println(list); // prints out each row.
      }
```

Say you wanted to convert it to an `int[][]` array interating thru all individual elements.

```java
      int[][] ints = new int[listofLists.size()][];

      for (int i = 0; i < listofLists.size(); i++) {
         // get each list in succession
         List<Integer> list = listofLists.get(i);
         // allocate the columns array to the size
         ints[i] = new int[list.size()];
         // copy each item over individually
         for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
            ints[i][k] = list.get(k);
         }
      }

      // print the arrays
      for (int[] i : ints) {
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
      }
```